# Adding values to charts in R Leaflet.minicharts

Tags: r, leaflet

I want to add values above my chart, using **lealfet.minicharts** package.

My current code looks like this

```
addMinicharts(
87.2180, -45.3496,
chartdata = c(20, 40),
colorPalette = c("darkred", "darkblue"),
width = 45, height = 45, popup = popupArgs(
labels = c("Test1", "Test2")), showLabels = TRUE, labelText = TRUE)
```

It gives me a chart with a labels "true" and pop-up window with labels and values. But I would like to have values (not labels) on the top of charts or inside on bars (instead of text).

Looking into [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leaflet.minicharts/leaflet.minicharts.pdf) and cannot figure it out. 
Thanks

[image: Map]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved myself.

I disabled **labelText = TRUE** and increased width/height. It fixed everything.

Current code

```
addMinicharts(
87.2180, -45.3496,
chartdata = c(20, 40),
colorPalette = c("darkred", "darkblue"),
width = 100, height = 100, popup = popupArgs(
  labels = c("Test1", "Test2")), showLabels = TRUE)
```

[image: Map]